# Import Aptana Dark theme to PyCharm

Tags: ide, themes, aptana, pydev, pycharm

I'm currently using Aptana studio, but have plans to move to PyCharm IDE. Is there any way to export a color scheme from Aptana to use it in PyCharm?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, but you can [import TextMate color schemes](https://github.com/JetBrains/colorSchemeTool).